# Locking Mouse to a single screen

Tags: linux, multi-monitor, xinput

I want to lock the mouse to a single monitor in a multi-monitor setup.
I tried the following:

```
MOUSE=`grep -i 'optical mouse' <(xinput --list --name-only)`
MONITOR=`awk '/HDMI.* con/ {print $1}' <(xrandr)`

xinput map-to-output' "$MOUSE" "$MONITOR"
```

Which doesn't do anything. As i understand the man-pages, this should recalculate and apply the "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" for the specific input device.

What am I doing wrong, what alternatives are there to dynamically attach and detach a pointer to a display?

I want to enable and disable the locking on the fly, so no manipulation of the `Xorg.conf` file.